# How to extract PDF text with Google Vision API in C#

Tags: c#, pdf, .net-core, ocr, google-vision

I want to use Google Vision in order to extract PDF into text/table. My PDF includes a table which I want to extract (`BlockType` = table).

I am not sure how to do that in C# though.

I installed `Google.Cloud.Vision.API` NuGet and tried to use the `DetectTextDocument` method but it seems that it receives only image.

```cs
var client = new ImageAnnotatorClientBuilder
{
    CredentialsPath = @"myjsonfile.json"
}.Build();

Image image = Image.FromUri("https://storage.cloud.google.com/pathtomyfile.pdf");

TextAnnotation response = client.DetectDocumentText(image); // Getting error for a bad image.
```

Then I tried to find any files methods and found the `BatchAnnotateFilesAsync` but I am not sure how to build the `BatchAnnotateFilesRequest` object that it requires and can't find any examples in `C#`.

Can anyone help me to figure out how to extract PDF document into text of a table block types?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
private string ScanPDFWithGoogle(string path)
      {

          string ret = string.Empty;
          try
          {
             
              var image = Google.Cloud.Vision.V1.Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\ADMIN\Downloads\parts.png");
              Log.Write("In  photoread try catch block : " + image.ToString());
              var credentialPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"];
              Log.Write("In  photoread try catch block after credential : " + credentialPath);
              GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(credentialPath);
              var channel = new Grpc.Core.Channel(
              ImageAnnotatorClient.DefaultEndpoint.ToString(),
              credential.ToChannelCredentials());
              ImageAnnotatorClient client = ImageAnnotatorClient.Create(channel);
              Log.Write("Channel" + client.ToString());
              var response = client.DetectText(image);
              ret = response.ToString();
              return ret;
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              Log.Write("Error at photoread api" + ex.Message);
              Log.Write(ex.StackTrace);
              throw ex;
          }


      }
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?